# $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=?$

I'm trying to turn $\frac{1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$ into separate fractions that can eventually cancel each other out but I can't find one. Is there an easier way to do this?
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\frac{2}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{(r+2)-r}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{1}{r(r+1)}-\frac{1}{(r+1)(r+2)}
$$ then by summing from $r=1$ to $r=n$ terms [telescope](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

$$\frac{1}{r(r+1)(r+2)} = 
\frac{1}{2}\left\{ {\frac{1}{r(r+1)} - \frac{1}{(r+1)(r+2)}} \right\}$$